# How to efficiently store a task information on a year calender

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-efficient

I have an embedded system (MCU without any OS) that the end-user should be able to define the system's level (scale: 0-100) for a year. As an example (time x day matrix):

```
       | 1st Jan | 2nd Jan | 3rd Jan | .. | 31 Dec |
00:30  |  40 (%) | 40      |  45     | .. |   50   |
01:48  |  48     | 47      |  55     | .. |   33   |
02:26  |  64     | 64      |  60     | .. |   68   |
..     |  ..     | ..      |  ..     | .. |   ..   |
22:15  | 79      | 82      |  89     | .. |   100  |
23:37  | 100     | 100     |  97     | .. |   100  |
```

What I thought is to store the data as: `time [in minutes], sysLevel`
 so it would be something like this for the above table:

```
 typedef struct{
   uint16_t minute; //scale: 0 - 1440 min
   uint8_t level; //scale 0 - 100 (%)
 }timeLevel_t; //3 byte
```

then store each day as

```
timeLevel_t firstJan[24] = { .. }; //it stores level changes, the array length doesn't have to be 24
timeLevel_t secJan[17] = { .. };
timeLevel_t thirdJan[20] = { .. };
...
```

(I will fetch the data from a CSV file it might be out of topic to consider it now on this question).

The system would expect to have a per hour task definition in the worst case, so that timeLevel_t (3 byte) definition for 24 hr would be 72 byte data per day, then the data for 365 days would be 26280 byte data.

Would you suggest a more memory efficient algorithm to store the information for a calender year (the program will update it each year so that it would consider the 29th Feb)?

In addition? Would it be better to make a 2 dimensional array to store day information on 1D, and timeLevel_t on the other dimension?

Comment: Seems to me that the source of the data (you mention a CSV file) is a very important part of the system design. I think you need to be more specific about where the data is being stored (flash/ram/network drive) and how the data is being accessed.

Comment: 0-1440 requires 11 bits and 0-100 requires 7 bits, so you need 18 bits for each entry. Perhaps you can squeeze it down to 16 bits by lowering the resolution to 2 minutes and 2 percentage points? You can also pack four 18-bit entries in 9 bytes, but it complicates the code a bit.

Comment: I will store the info on internal memory of the MCU (more than 2.62 kB), and update the data via the network (could be updated block by block (months) ). I think the ideal source of data should be considered to not to lose the focus of the question (it is once a year process).

Comment: I was also considering squeezing the bits, but couldn't find a way to do it in a smart way. I wonder if it is possible to compress(code) the data and just decompress(decode) the current day's data and remove the old data

Comment: If you have 26280 bytes of uncompressed data and 2620 bytes in which to store that data, you need a compression ration of 10:1. Or to put it another way, you need to be able to encode each event with an average of 2 bits/event.  That's not likely to happen. And if the 2.62kB of memory is also being used for code and other data, then things are even worse.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store additional information, such as the #days/month, or assume 31 each and waste a couple of bytes.

It kind of all depends on your pain points. You could pack bytes more to have no bits wasted, at the expense of code complexity and compute time.

If storage is at an absolute premium, You could store everything in just one huge 1D array and use the extra bits for other stuff.
For instance, bit 11 could indicate "next day", bit 12 "next month" and then you can crawl the array and find any day of the year. And you'd have a whole other 4 bits for various shenanigans.

Describe the issues more, please.